# scp files in a certain order using ls

Tags: scp, ls

Whenever I try to SCP files (in bash), they end up in a seemingly random(?) order.
I've found a simple but not-very-elegant way of keeping a desired order, described below. Is there a clever way of doing it?

**Edit:** deleted my early solution from here, cleaned, adapted using other suggestions, and added as an answer below.

Comment: I'm curious: why does the order of creation of the files on the target machine matter? And what's your question?

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate file?

Comment: Two things: 1. Without special (and unusual) filesystem modifications, most UNIX systems are [incapable of telling you when a file was created](http://userprimary.net/posts/2007/11/18/ctime-in-unix-means-last-change-time-not-create-time/). The best they can do is `mtime`, which is last-modified-time. 2. `ls -lr` would list the files in lexicographical order, not any kind of time-based ordering.

Comment: Thanks!
lurker: I'm working with simulation files, so I need to know which comes first.
merlin2011: I don't at all! I just couldn't find a clever way to do this.
kojiro: thanks for the correction. Certainly I meant ls -rt. Fixed now. I'm working locally on a Mac, and running simulations on a remote server on Scientific Linux, I think. They both have an order of creation (time-date).

Comment: @user3532942: Why don't you just add a timestamp to the files (e.g. encoded in the filename)? Also, what's your question?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: my implicit question was "what's the clever way to do this?". I'll go on and change my wording above, sorry about that. Yes, I could add a time stamp, but I have so many files and the names are so long already that I'd much rather remove another layer of name-complexity. Also, the names are generated by the software I'm using, so I'd have to rename everything.

Comment: @user3532942: Fair enough. I personally would rather add complexity to the name than rely on timestamps carrying import information to be 100% in sync on different systems (this e.g. complicates backups). You could probably just rename your output files with a script after production.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: you're absolutely right, but in my particular case I only need the order, the times themselves are not relevant except in relative terms.

Comment: See also this question at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/345884).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To send files from a local machine (e.g. your laptop) to a remote (e.g. your calculation server), you can use Merlin2011's clever solution:

1. Go into the folder in your local machine where you want to copy files from.
2. Execute the `scp` command, assuming you have an access key for the remote server:
   `scp -r $(ls -rt) user@foo.bar:/where/you/want/them/.`

**Note:** if you don't have a public access key it may be better to do something similar using `tar`, then send the tar file, i.e. `tar -zcvf files.tar.gz $(ls -rt)`, and then send that tar file on its own using `scp`.

---

But to do it the other way around you might not be able to run the `scp` command directly from the remote server to send files to, say, your laptop. Instead, you may need to, let's say *bring* files into your laptop. My brute-force solution is:

1. In the remote server, `cd` into the folder you want to copy files from.
2. Create a list of the files in the order you want. For example, for reverse order of creation (most recent copied last):
   `ls -rt > ../filenames.txt`
3. Now you need to add the path to each file name. Before you go up to the directory where the list is, print the path using `pwd`. Now do go up: `cd ..`
4. You now need to add this path to each file name in the list. There are many ways to do this, here's one using awk:
   `cat filenames.txt | awk '{print "path/to/files/" $0}' > delete_me.txt`
5. You need the filenames to be in the same line, separated by a space, so change newlines to spaces:
   `tr '\n' ' ' < delete_me.txt > filenames.txt`
6. Get filenames.txt to the local server, and put it in the folder where you want to copy the files into.
7. The scp run would be:
   `scp -r user@foo.bar:"$(cat filenames.txt)" .`

Similarly, this assumes you have a private access key, otherwise it's much simpler to `tar` the file in the remote, and bring that.

Answer (score 6):

One can achieve file transfer with alphabetical order using `rsync`:

```
rsync -P -e ssh -r user@remote_host:/some_path local_path
```

`P` allows partial downloading, `e` sets the SSH protocol and `r` downloads recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line without an intermediate using `xargs`:

```
 ls -r <directory> | xargs -I {} scp <Directory>/{} user@foo.bar:folder/
```

Of course, this would require you to type your password multiple times if you do not have public key authentication.

You can also use `cd` and still skip the intermediate file.

```
 cd <directory>
 scp $(ls -r) user@foo.bar:folder/
```

Comment: On OS X, `ls -r` will reverse the order of the files listed. But by default, `ls` lists the files in lexicographical order, not by age.

Comment: @kojiro, That is also true on Linux. However, the OP did not explicitly specify which order he actually wanted, only that he wanted to a particular order. Moreover, he used the `-r` flag in his own commands (without `-t`), so I assume that was the ordering he desired.

Comment: @merlin2011: very helpful suggestion to simplify my code. I've done so in the original (and credited you). How about the other way around? i.e., this would work from local to remote, how about copying from the remote? I still can't think of any other way than the one I used.