# Order of files pulled by scp -r

Tags: scp

What order does `scp -r` pull files? I don't intend to control the order like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067175/scp-files-in-a-certain-order-using-ls) but just curious to know why that particular order.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23067175/1531971 (Though I think this is off-topic, actually. Maybe better researched over on https://superuser.com/ ?)

Comment: And it is pretty much answered on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/751414/609232

Comment: @jdv I've hyperlinked the related SO post already in the question

Comment: @jdv Thanks! The link is what I'm looking for :)